# CSS multiple selection with square brackets

Tags: css

I have this piece of code on my website:

```
#stage-1-picture,
#stage-2-picture,
#stage-3-picture,
#stage-5-picture {
    margin-top: 20px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

I have been wondering if there is a way to shorten this multiple selection with square brackets so that I could use some kind of a plceholder in place of the numbers 1,2,3,4,5.

Thank you!

Comment: You need to go for SASS.

Comment: You *probably* need to add a *class* (e.g. "`stage-picture`") to your elements. SASS is great but might be overkill here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not *really*, not without resorting to some kind of poor man's regex selector. However, it *can* be done using some CSS3 [attribute selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors):

```css
p[id^="item-"][id$="-test"] { color: red; }
```

```html
<p id="item-1-test">Test 1 (should be red)</p>
<p id="item-1-test">Test 2 (should be red)</p>
<p id="item-1">Without last part (should not be red)</p>
<p id="1-test">Without first part (should not be red)</p>
<p id="different">Totally different (should not be red)</p>
<p id="item--test">Warning! Incorrectly red.</p>
```

The CSS rule selects only elements that start with "item-" and end with "-test".

However, I recommend looking at different approaches, be it SASS, jQuery, or reworking your strategy alltogether: it seems like you need `class="stage-picture"` on your elements...

Comment: Thank you for this "quick&dirty" method :). Maybe it doesn't look the neatest, but it does the trick. I intentionally did not want to mention SASS or class selectors so this must ba an accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to go with sass as Suresh told. A solution with sass would be:

```
%temp {
  margin-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

@for $i from 1 through 5 {

  #stage-#{$i}-picture {
    @extend %temp;
  }
}
```

An example: http://sassmeister.com/gist/904fb5c267e5ddfe0c8a

Comment: Thank you for this usesul piece of SASS. As I wrote in a separate comment, I intenionally did not want to resort to SASS in this cast, but this snippet is helpful anywany.

Comment: Yes it's just for encyclopaedic knowledge :)

Answer (score 0):

You would probably use preprocessors like SASS or LESS. However much more natural to use classes for your task, since this is exactly what you need: target set of elements having similar characteristics:

```
.stage-picture {
    margin-top: 20px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="stage-picture" id="stage-1-picture"></div>
<div class="stage-picture" id="stage-2-picture"></div>
<!-- etc ... -->
```

Comment: Sure this would be the neatest way, but I used id's on purpose in this question. Anyway, thanks for this clear reminder what classes are for.